# get_queried_object_id combined with wp_redirect gets wrong id

Tags: plugin-development, slug, wp-redirect

I have the following snippet of code that I am experimenting to restrict access to certain wordpress pages through a plugin.

It works... almost. The browser is redirected to the login page, but the query string is wrong. The query string has the id and slug for the login page and not the page it was redirected from. I want to use this info to redirect back to the page that sent the user to the login page.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_login_page' );
function redirect_to_login_page() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() || is_page('login') ) return;

    $postId = get_queried_object_id();
    $slug = get_queried_object()->post_name;
    wp_redirect( '/login?r='.$postId.'&s='.$slug, 302 ); 
    exit;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this does not give me the id and slug from the original page?

Comment: How about using [`wp_get_referer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_referer/) - `wp_redirect( wp_get_referer() )` ?

Comment: So use that on the login page. Yes that might be an idea. The only thing is that the login form posts to itself and then it itself becomes the referer. Do you know by any chance what action to hook into, to catch a successful login and do the redirect after that?

Comment: Actually, the issue is with the `s` parameter. Try changing it to `s2` or another name. But why are you sending the slug? You could've just use `get_post_field()` or `get_post()` to retrieve the post slug based on the post ID.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! What is with the s parameter?

Comment: I don't need the slug. I sent that for debugging purposes.

Comment: I see. And the `s` parameter is reserved for search queries - `example.com/?s=keyword` and `example.com/sample-page/?s=keyword` both causes WordPress to search for `keyword`. And in your case, the original slug gets "lost" because of double redirects - first to `/login?r=<id>&s=<keyword>` and finally to `/login?r=<id>&s=login` - the first redirect ends up with "not found" error where `is_page()` returns `false` which explains why the 2nd redirect happens.